# Differences between require a builtin library or just invoking it like ~<library>

Tags: javascript, node.js

I noticed that in Nodejs I can invoke any builtin library without requiring it. Instead of:

```
var assert = require('assert');
assert.deepEqual(...);
```

I can do the following:

```
~assert.deepEqual(..);
```

Where is this syntax explained in the Node documentation?
I assume its better for separating custom libraries requires from builtin ones, making the require section smaller, but I really wonder, Is there any official doc on this?
Is it preferred over the usual require methodology in nodejs?
Is there a way to use it for custom libraries as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That syntax isn't specific to Node, it's just the [Bitwise NOT](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_NOT) operator in JavaScript.

What that syntax does is evaluates a function as an expression and invokes it.

Essentially, it does the same as an IIFE, in a slightly more convoluted manner.

```js
// these are functionally the same
(function() {
  console.log('Called!');
})()

~function() {
  console.log('Me too!');
}()
```

Also, you must use `require` for the code you provided to work. Where it can work without `require` is in the Node REPL, because core modules are globals there. However, that also means using `~` is redundant since you can just call a global function directly.